# Google Analytics update a counter based on entries in databse

Tags: google-analytics, counter

Is it possible, and if so, how to make a "custom" counter entry in GA, which basically is a count based on database entries.

Answer (score 0):

Quite hard to say without knowing your specific use case, but Google Analytics supports [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide). You can send custom events to Analytics on every page load. You can then think of a structure with different categories and labels where you can filter these.

If you just want to show the change of the number of entries in a table, you could also think of using a monitoring software like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Think about whether your data makes sense together with your other Analytics data or if you just want to show the changes over time together with your other server health parameters.

Comment: I just want to have a "counter" visible in GA (to have all the statistics gathered in one place), and this "counter" is just a count of a db entries (or any other "static" number). Yeah, i aware of the event triggers.